# $A^TA=B^TB$. Is $A=QB$ for some orthogonal $Q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two real square matrices and $A^TA=B^TB$. Can we say that $A=QB$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$?

If they are vectors we have $\|a\|^2=a^Ta=b^Tb=\|b\|^2$, so intuitively clear, since we just have to rotate. But it is hard to picture the matrix case but I have not been able to show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes.  In particular, it suffices to show that for every matrix $A$, there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that
$$
A = U \sqrt{A^TA}
$$
which is to say that each matrix has a [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition).

Comment: Sorry but I do not really understand why it suffice to have a polar decomposition. Naively we have $A=U\sqrt{B^TB}$ but $\sqrt{B^TB}\neq B$ unless $B$ is symmetric, so I guess this is not the way to see this but I do not get it.

Comment: @user41467 That's not quite it. Instead, note that $A = U_1 P$ and $B = U_2 P$, where
$$
P = \sqrt{A^TA} = \sqrt{B^TB}
$$

Comment: Ah. $(U_1U_2^T)$ is orthogonal. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is also a nice geometric way to see this.

The geometric interpretation of the singular value decomposition says that a $(n\times n)$-matrix $A$ maps the unit $(n-1)$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a hyperellipsoid. The lengths of the axes of this ellipsoid are the roots of the eigenvalues of $A^T A$.

So if $A^T A = B^T B$, the matrices $A$ and $B$ map the unit $(n-1)$-sphere to congruent hyperellipsoids. Hence $A$ and $B$ must be the same up to an orthogonal matrix, which represents the isometry that maps one hyperellipsoid into the other.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!

Comment: @user41467 You're welcome!