# If $A^TA = B^TB$ where $B$ is non-square, does $\exists$ matrix $P$ such that $A=PB$?

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

This question has been answered before for the case where $A$ and $B$ are both square: [$A^TA=B^TB$. Is $A=QB$ for some orthogonal $Q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934844/ata-btb-is-a-qb-for-some-orthogonal-q)

I didn't really follow the algebraic explanation there but the geometric explanation in terms of hyperspheres is really nice.

Unfortunately, if $A$ is not square, then we can't use the hypersphere argument since $A$ and $B$ will map to spaces of different dimensionality. Furthermore, $P$ will not be orthogonal as it is in the above case.

So, let's suppose $A$ has dimension $k \times k$ and $B$ has dimension $d \times k$ with $k<d$. Is is still true that there exists a matrix $P$ such that $A=PB$? $P$ will need to have dimension $k \times d$.

Comment: One can find an answer [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1996.12004770?journalCode=uamm20)

Answer (score 1):

Let $B\in\mathbb R^{d\times k}$, where $k<d$. Let $M$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^d$ such that $\text{im}B\subset M\subset\mathbb R^d$ and $\dim M = k$. Then there is a unitary operator $W : M\to\mathbb R^k$. Extend $W$ by setting $Wx =0$ for $x\in M^\perp$. Then $W : \mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^k$ such that $W^TWy = y$ for $y\in M$. *)

Consider $C = WB\in\mathbb R^{k\times k}$. Then $C^TC = B^TW^TWB = B^TB$ and therefore $WB = C = Q(C^TC)^{1/2} = Q(B^TB)^{1/2}$. Hence, $B = W^TQ(B^TB)^{1/2}$. Setting $V = W^TQ$, you have $B = V(B^TB)^{1/2}$ with an isometry $V\in\mathbb R^{d\times k}$ (i.e., $V^TV = I_k$). Hence
$$
A = U(A^TA)^{1/2} = U(B^TB)^{1/2} = UV^TB.
$$

---

*) To see this, let $y\in M$ and $x\in \mathbb R^d$, $x = u+v$ with $u\in M$ and $v\in M^\perp$. Then
$$
(W^TWy,x) = (Wy,Wx) = (Wy,Wu) = (y,u) = (y,u+v) = (y,x).
$$
Thus, $W^TWy = y$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that we can decompose B into a length preserving map $V$ and then $(B^TB)^{1/2}$ which rescales everything to get original B. Is this how I should understand this? Also, why does $V^{-1}=V^T$?

Comment: $V$ is not invertible. But $V^TV = I$. The rest of your comment I did not understand.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you can write $B=V(B^TB)^{1/2}$?

Comment: I edited.......

Comment: dim $M$ = $k$ because the rank of $B$ is at most $k$?

Comment: @user11128 Exactly. That's why. The rank could be $k$. In this case $M = \text{im}B$.

Comment: Ok. And last piece I'm confused with is the extension of $W$. Why are we interested in extending it? Before extending, we still had $W^TWy=y$ for $y \in M$; we can use your proof with $x=u$ to see this, can't we?

Comment: @user11128 Good point. I just want it to be a $k\times d$ matrix to have $W^T$ defined.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $A^TA=B^TB$ has a minimal diagonalization $V\Sigma^2V^T$, minimal in the sense of leaving out zero eigenvalues. Then $V$ is isometric, $V^TV=I_k$ and $Σ$ is diagonal of full rank $k$.

As in the classical construction of the SVD, where we aim at a factorization $A=U_AΣV^T$, $B=U_BΣV^T$, construct the matrices $U_A=AVΣ^{-1}$, $V_B=BVΣ^{-1}$, then $U_A^T U_A^{\,}=I_k$, $U_B^TU_B=I_k$ so that also these matrices are also isometric. To actually be the missing factors of the SVDs, one would have to prove that $A=[AVΣ^{-1}]ΣV^T=AVV^T$, that is, that the projector $(I-VV^T)$ has its image in the kernel of $A$, which is a standard fact for the orthogonormal eigenbasis of $A^TA$.

In conclusion, with $P=U_AU_B^T$ we get
$$
PB=U_AU_B^T(U_BΣV^T)=U_AΣV^T=A.
$$

Comment: Why can you conclude from $V_B\Sigma^2V_B^T = V_A\Sigma^2V_A^T$ that $V_A = V_B$?

Comment: @amsmath : $M=A^TA=B^TB$ is the same matrix, one matrix, one diagonalization. Your objection would be valid if I had started from the SVDs of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Ok, then. How do you get from $B^TB = V\Sigma^2V^T$ to $B = U_B\Sigma V^T$? I know it's true, but this has to be shown (which BTW I do in my answer).

Comment: The statement I claim you have to prove is actually nothing but the original claim (with $A = \Sigma V^T$). So, you prove the claim by using it. ;-)

Comment: Why does the SVD of $A$ and $B$ involve the same matrix $V$ from the eigendecomposition of $A^TA=B^TB$?

Comment: I construct $U_A$ and $U_B$ so that the slim SVDs of $A$ and $B$ has the same factors $Σ$ and $V$. Of course one still would have to prove that $A$ is actually equal to $(AVΣ^{-1})ΣV^T=AVV^T$, that is, that $(I-VV^T)$ is a projector onto the kernel of $A$.

Comment: Got it at last ha!

Comment: Yes, the SVD is more or less unique, up to rotations in spaces of equal singular values and sign flips in the singular vector pairs. The matrix identity you start with ensures that the SVDs have equal singular values and right singular vectors spanning the same sub-spaces.

Comment: It could be easier not to assume that $V_A=V_B$ and start with $A^TA=B^TB$ implying that $(A^TA)^{1/2}=(B^TB)^{1/2}$, i.e. $V_A\Sigma V_A^T=V_B\Sigma V_B^T$. Now $$A=U_A\Sigma V_A^T=U_AV_A^T(V_A\Sigma V_A^T)=U_AV_A^T(V_B\Sigma V_B^T)=U_AV_A^TV_BU_B^T B.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you like the geometrical argument, I want to point out that there actually is an argument with hyperspheres and relate this geometrical viewpoint with the other answers.

Consider a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$, which can be regarded as a a linear map $B\colon\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^d$. By the SVD, $B$ maps the $(k-1)$-dimensional hypersphere $S^{k-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ onto a $(n-1)$-dimensional ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $n$ is the number of non-zero singular values of $B$.

- **Case 1. $k \leq d$.** $B(S^{k-1})$ is an ellipsoid lying in an $k$-dimensional subspace $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$. 
  If $B$ is full-rank, all singular values are non-zero and $\mathrm{im}\,B = M$. The map $B$ is an embedding of the sphere into $\mathbb{R}^d$. If $B$ doesn't have full rank, $\mathrm{im}\,B$ is a subspace of $M$. Note that in amsmath's answer the map $W$ describes how $M$ lies in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
- **Case 2. $k > d$.** Also in this case there is an interpretation. The intersection of $S^{k-1}$ and $(\ker B)^\perp$ is a subsphere. This subsphere is mapped onto an ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^d$. So $B$ can be regarded as a kind of projection of the hypersphere onto a subsphere, and this subsphere is then mapped onto an ellipsoid.

Now let's look at your question. By the condition $A^T A = B^T B$, the ellipsoids  $A(S^{k-1}) \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $B(S^{k-1}) \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ have axes with equal lengths. So the matrix $P$ maps the axes of the ellipsoid $B(S^{k-1})$ onto the corresponding axes of $A(S^{k-1})$. And this is exactly what the map $P$ does. Using Lutzl's notations, $P=U_A U_B^T$. Now, $U_B^T$ maps unit vectors in the directions of the axes of $B(S^{k-1})$ to the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Consequently $U_A$ maps this basis onto the unit vectors in the directions of the axes of $A(S^{k-1})$.