# SVD decomposition of a square matrix of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

Le $M$ be any matrix in $C^{n \times n}$. Consider the matrix $MM^*$.
This matrix is Hermitian ($(MM^*)^* = MM^*$), and positive semi-definite
($\forall v^*, v^*MM^* v = (v^* M) (M^* v) = (v^*M) (v^*M)^* = |v^*M)|^2 \geq 0$).
Thus, its eigenvalues have to be real and non-negative numbers (for an Hermitian $H$, $\lambda v^* v =  v^* H v = v^* H^* v = \overline{\lambda} v^* v$).
Thus, the Spectral Theorem can be applied to $MM^*$. Therefore, $MM^* = {UDU}^*$, where U is an unitary matrix, and $D$  is a diagonal matrix composed of
the eigenvalues of $MM^*$. Let $\Sigma$ be the diagonal matrix composed of the square roots
of the eigenvalues of $MM^*$ (i.e., the singular values of $M$). Then, ${D} = \Sigma \Sigma =  \Sigma \Sigma^*$,
since the Hermitian transpose does not have any effect on
a diagonal matrix composed of real numbers.
Thus,
\begin{eqnarray*}
MM^* & = & {UDU}^* = U \Sigma \Sigma^* U^*= (U \Sigma I) (I^* \Sigma^* U^*) = (U \Sigma I) (U \Sigma I)^*.
\end{eqnarray*}
This implies that $M = U \Sigma I$.
As well as $M = U \Sigma V$, for any unitary matrix. Which is impossible! What did I miss?

Comment: The fact that $AA^* = BB^*$ does not imply that $A = B$. That's what you missed.

Comment: [See this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2934844/81360)

Answer (score 0):

From
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^*=I\,I^*
$$
you cannot conclude that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=I.
$$